# Delete option values in select block in HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select, dropdown

I need to delete option value tags inside select elements like this:

```
     <select name="name">

 <option value="something1">First</option>
 <option value="something2">Second</option>
      </select>
```

So what I need to do is to find a way to delete value="something" with Javascript, so I end up with something like this :

```
     <select name="name">

 <option>First</option>
 <option>Second</option>
      </select>
```

How to do this with Javascript?

Comment: Do you know how to find the of elements? Do you know JavaScript at all?

Comment: I guess you are looking for `removeAttribute("value");`. Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Find the options using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
>
> To remove `attribute` use
>   [`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

```js
 var options = document.querySelectorAll('[name="name"] option');
 for (var i = 0, iLen = options.length; i < iLen; i++) {
   options[i].removeAttribute('value');
 }
```

```html
<select name="name">
  <option value="something1">First</option>
  <option value="something2">Second</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think you are partially correct, as i guess he asked for to remove only those which are having value="somethingx". If value != "somethingx" do not delete value. Still you can be 100% correct, but this is what i guess.

Comment: @divy3993, his expected result does not expect it.,I guess. Otherwise count of options would be less in results!